# How to use DataTable as ItemsSource of my DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, closedxml

I want to load an Excel-file into my `DataGrid`. Using `ClosedXML`.

I have this method:

```
public static DataTable ImportExceltoDataTable(string filePath, string sheetName) {

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new(filePath)) {

        IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
        DataTable dt = new();

        bool firstRow = true;
        foreach (IXLRow row in ws.Rows()) {

            if (firstRow) {
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells()) {
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.CachedValue.ToString());
                }
                
                firstRow = false;

            } else {
      
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
          
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(row.FirstCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber, row.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber)) {
                
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i} = cell.CachedValue.ToString();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
 
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Here's my click-event:

```
OpenFileDialog of = new();
of.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx;";
of.Title = "Import Excel file.";

if (of.ShowDialog()==true) {

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = ImportExceltoDataTable("...", "...").DefaultView;
}
```

**I am trying to achieve the following**

- Click a button, choose an Excel-file, populate my `DataGrid` with its contents.

**Updated after adding solution provided by @mm8:**

I now get an `Empty extension is not supported` error, as I don't know how to connect the `OpenFileDialog`-selection of the click-event, to the initiation of the `DataTable`.

Very grateful for any assistance!

Comment: What do you mean by "binding"?
If you write the value returned by the method to a property; this property notifies about its change through the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event; and in XAML in the UI property of the element is set {Binding ....} from this property with the DataTable - then there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `ItemsSource` to the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable`:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = ImportExceltoDataTable("...", "...").DefaultView;
```

Unlike a `DataTable`, a `DataView` implements the required `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: I see, thanks for that.
In addition to my method, I have a click-event. I am failing in combining the two.
I will add some code to my initial question. Please have a look, if you don't mind.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Where do you get an exception exactly?

Comment: at `using (XLWorkbook workBook = new(filePath)) {`
It's not talking to the `OpenFileDialog`, is it? So I guess it's not so weird it's not getting the filepath of the document I selected (assuming that is the issue)

Comment: Your original question was about "How to use DataTable as ItemsSource of my DataGrid" and I believe it has already been answered.

Comment: you are right, I will edit my question, and set your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: And then ask a new question if you have another issue please.